# Spring web service template set MustUnderstand to none or false

Tags: java, soap, spring-boot, soap-client, spring-ws

How to set MustUnderstand to none or false. I'm using spring boot and web service template to create client.

**POM.xml**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-ws</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

**Config**

```
@Configuration
public class BrokerConnectionServiceConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private LuiUrlBuilder luiUrlBuilder;    

    @Bean
    public Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller() {
        Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
        marshaller.setPackagesToScan("com.example");
        return marshaller;
    }    

    @Bean
    public BrokerConnectionServiceClient brokerConnectionServiceClient(Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller) {
        BrokerConnectionServiceClient client = new BrokerConnectionServiceClient();
        client.setDefaultUri(luiUrlBuilder.getConnectionServiceUri());
        client.setMarshaller(marshaller);
        client.setUnmarshaller(marshaller);

        return client;
    }
```

**BrokerConnectionServiceClient.java**

```
public class BrokerConnectionServiceClient extends WebServiceGatewaySupport {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(BrokerConnectionServiceClient.class);

    @Autowired
    private LuiUrlBuilder luiUrlBuilder;    

    public void getBrokerConnectionServiceData(ConnectionRequestType connectionRequestType) {

        log.debug("inside getBrokerConnectionServiceData");

        try {
            getWebServiceTemplate()
                    .marshalSendAndReceive(
                            new JAXBElement<>(new QName(Constants.BROKER_CONNECTION_SERVICE_NAMESPACE_URI, Constants.BROKER_CONNECTION_SERVICE_LOCAL_PART), ConnectionRequestType.class, connectionRequestType),
                            new ActionCallback(new URI(luiUrlBuilder.getConnectionServiceCallBackLocation()), new Addressing200408()));
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            log.trace("URISyntaxException occurred", e);
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Can some body please let me know how to set "`Must understand`" to none or false and **WS-A version** to "**200508**" instead of "**200408**"?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using WebServiceMessageCallback we can achieve. ActionCallback intern implements WebServiceMessageCallback.

**BrokerConnectionServiceClient.java**

```
getWebServiceTemplate()
.marshalSendAndReceive(
      new JAXBElement<>(new QName(Constants.BROKER_CONNECTION_SERVICE_NAMESPACE_URI, Constants.BROKER_CONNECTION_SERVICE_LOCAL_PART), ConnectionRequestType.class, connectionRequestType),
      new WebServiceMessageCallback() {
      @Override
      public void doWithMessage(WebServiceMessage message) throws IOException, TransformerException {
      SOAPMessage soapMessage = ((SaajSoapMessage) message).getSaajMessage();
      SOAPHeader soapHeader = soapMessage.getSOAPHeader();

      SOAPHeaderElement actionElement = soapHeader.addHeaderElement(new QName("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing", "Action", "wsa"));
      actionElement.setMustUnderstand(false);
      actionElement.setTextContent("ConnectionService");
    }
});
```

**OUTPUT**

```
<wsa:Action soapenv:mustUnderstand="0">ConnectionService</wsa:Action>
```

same for remaining fields too.